# get path of a file that lives in desktop using rails

Tags: ruby, hash, ruby-on-rails-5, digest-authentication

I want to save the path of a file that lives in the desktop but seem that rails can not recognise it with the path specified. I tried this:

```
 def calculate_hash
    require 'digest'
    file_path = "Users/crs/Desktop/index.xml"
    sha1 = Digest::SHA1.file file_path
    puts "Checksum SHA1: #{sha1.hexdigest}"
  end
```

If I run this method I get an error saying " No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /Users/crsDesktop/index.xml
"
Please hep me how I can make it recognisable.

Comment: Does it work with `file_path = "~/Users/crs/Desktop/index.xml"`?

Comment: That error doesn't match what you're opening. Can you double-check what you're doing and verify it's coming from this code?

Answer (score 0):

Since `Users` is a root directory you must specify the full path:

```
file_path = "/Users/crs/Desktop/index.xml"
```

Notice the `/` prefix.

Another thing to note is paths use slash (`/`) and *not* backslash (`\\`). If you use a backslash by accident it will "disappear" in most cases:

```
file_path = "/Users/crs\Desktop/index.xml"
# => "/Users/crsDesktop/index.xml"
```

Where `\D` has special meaning within double-quoted strings and means, in this case, *literal capital D*.